# Right-censored survival fit with JAGS

Tags: survival, markov-chain-montecarlo, jags, censoring, weibull-distribution

**Update: I got the JAGS model running and this eliminates the distracting part of my question. It's really about the proper preparation of data for dinterval() and inits.**

I can't find a concrete example of preparing right-censored survival data for use in JAGS when starting with a vector of times and a vector of censored status. The examples I've seen all have a constant censoring time.

My two questions are:

1. What is the correct way to prepare dinterval(t[i], c[i]) when you are starting with a vector of event times and a matching vector of censored/failed status?
2. What is the reason for supplying a initial value vector of event times where *uncensored* times are set to NA and *censored* times are set to a value > than the observed censoring time? I'm really struggling to understand that.

**Update: I think I have the answer to (2). Apparently JAGS complains if you try to overwrite values in the init vector, but if the vector is initialized to NA it works.**

Note that my understanding of these requirements comes from looking at existing online examples. If the requirements are unfounded I'd love to learn that.

I created a short test using the aml data set from the survival package which does a survival fit then tries to fit a Weibull distribution using JAGS and add those points for comparison. Originally I thought you had to pass zeros in for the unscensored times in c[i] for dinterval(t[i], c[i]), but that causes an error:

> Error in node is.censored[1]
>   Observed node inconsistent with observed parents at initialization.
>   Try setting appropriate initial values.

Here is my sample R script. Some lines seem to be indented too much, not sure why. I converted all tabs to spaces and it looks clean in my edit window:

```
# Right-censoring test
require(survival)
require(runjags)
graphics.off()
rm(fit, S, results)

# SURVIVAL FIT AND PLOT
fit <- survfit(Surv(aml$time, aml$status) ~ 1, conf.type = "log-log")
plot(fit, xlab = "time", ylab = "survival", main = "AML survival")

# JAGS WEIBULL FIT WITH CENSORING
# Model uses three different versions of observed times.
# t.orig is the original set of observed times including censored times.
# t.mod has the censored times set to NA.
# t.cens is the set I have questions about. Currently the same as t.orig
# but is that the proper choice?
#
model <- "model {
    for(i in 1:N) {
        is.censored[i] ~ dinterval(t.mod[i], t.cens[i])
        t.mod[i] ~ dweib(a, b)
        S[i] <- 1 - pweib(t.orig[i], a, b)
    }
    a ~ dgamma(3.5, 2)
    b ~ dgamma(1.5, 100)
}"

censored <- !aml$status
    t.orig <- aml$time
t.mod <- aml$time
    t.mod[censored] <- NA
    t.cens <- aml$time
# Online examples seem to indicate special treatment of the c[i]
# passed to dinterval(t[i], c[i]), changing the uncensored times.
#t.cens[!censored] <- 0 # THIS CAUSES AN ERROR

data <- dump.format(list(
    t.orig = t.orig,
    t.mod = t.mod,
    N = length(t.mod),
    t.cens = t.cens,
    is.censored = as.numeric(censored)  
))

# Apparently you must provide initial values of the time vector
# with uncensored times of NA and censored times > the observed time.
# I don't understand this requirement at all.
t.init <- rep(NA, length(t.mod))
t.init[censored] <- t.cens[censored] + 1

inits <- c(
    dump.format(list(a = 1.1, b = 3.0e-4, t.mod = t.init)),
    dump.format(list(a = 2.3, b = 0.02, t.mod = t.init))
)
results = run.jags(model, monitor=c("S", "a", "b"), data=data, inits=inits)
S <- print(results, vars="S")
points(aml$time, S[,4], col="blue", pch=19)
    segments(aml$time, S[,1], aml$time, S[,3], col="blue", lwd=2)
```

Thanks for taking the time to look at this.

Comment: I'm having trouble following the model and this seems to be where the error lies... I find a hierarchical drawing showing "is distributed as" and "is equal to" with the priors can be helpful when visualizing these. Perhaps more comments in the model text also?

Comment: I edited the code to do a fit without the censored data and prove that the model and priors work. Basically it's failure time distributed as F(t) = dweib(a, b), and survival probability S(t) = 1 - F(t). I think the error lies in how I am preparing the event data for use with dinterval.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I was asked to re-post this answer here from my comment at http://doingbayesiandataanalysis.blogspot.com/2012/01/complete-example-of-right-censoring-in.html
The specifics of this answer relate to the model in that comment, but the concepts apply to the topic here.

---

The core of the JAGS model for censored data is this:

```
isCensored[i] ~ dinterval( y[i] , censorLimitVec[i] )
y[i] ~ dnorm( mu , tau )
```

The key to understanding what JAGS is doing is that JAGS automatically imputes a random value for any variable that is not specified as a constant in the data. Thus, when `y[i]` is `NA` (i.e., a missing value, not a constant), then JAGS imputes a random value for it.

But what value should it generate?

The second line of the model, above, says that `y[i]` should be randomly generated from a normal distribution with mean mu and precision tau.

But the first line of the model, above, puts another constraint on the randomly generated value of `y[i]`. That line says that whatever value of `y[i]` is randomly generated, it must fall on the side of `censorLimitVec[i]` dictated by the value of `isCensored[i]`.

To understand this part, let's unpack the `dinterval()` distribution. Suppose that `censorLimitVec` has 3 values in it, not just 1:

```
censorLimitVec = c(10,20,30)
```

Then randomly generated values from `dinterval(y,c(10,20,30))` will be either 0, 1, 2, or 3 depending on whether $y<10$, $10 < y < 20$, $20<y<30$, or $30<y$. So, if $y=15$, `dinterval(y,c(10,20,30))` has output of $1$ with 100% probability. The trick is this: We instead specify the output of `dinterval`, and impute a random value of `y` that could produce it. Thus, if we say

```
1 ~ dinterval(y,c(10,20,30))
```

then `y` is imputed as a random value between 10 and 20.

Putting the two model statements together,

```
1 ~ dinterval( y , censorLimit )

y ~ dnorm( mu , tau )
```

means that `y` comes from a normal density and `y` must fall above the `censorLimit`.

Hope that helps!!

Comment: Because I still had problems understanding the dinterval() distribution I searched a bit and found [this presentation](http://www.math.helsinki.fi/openbugs/IceBUGS/Presentations/PlummerIceBUGS.pdf) by Martyn Plummer. Slide 14 really helped me understand the concept.